# Want to connect my shopping cart total price to a paypal checkout

Tags: php, paypal, checkout

I have a `displaycart.php` page where it displays all items I have in a shopping cart, each item has an `ItemUnitPrice` field where it shows the unit price of the item.

If I have say 6 items in the cart then I want to add up the total `ItemUnitPrice` fields and set that amount to be paid with PayPal.

I have checked out PayPals button features which they allow and you can only set a given price for the user to pay for when you create the button.

Is there a way I can link the PayPal button to my database so it shows the total of all the `ItemUnitPrice` fields.

The variable which holds the total `ItemUnitPrice`:

```
<?php
$Total = $Quantity * $ItemUnitPrice;
?>
```

The PayPal 'Pay Now' Button:

```
<html>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="KAMQ5PVWVDYYN">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif"    border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif"  width="1" height="1">
</form>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

Yeah I've done something stupidly wrong!

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_BLANK">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@asianweddingservices.org" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<? $ItemDesc ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?$ItemCode ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?$Total ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB" />
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF" />
<input src="paypal/purchase.png" name="Submit" type="image" value="purchase" alt="Purchase" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Change the set value to your total.

Show your code and I can edit the answer to fix it for you.

**Add this:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<? echo $Total; ?>" />
```

**If that doesn't work:**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_BLANK">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="PAYPAL EMAIL" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="ITEM NAME" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="CUSTOM VALUE" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="ITEM NUMBER" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="TOTAL" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB" />
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF" />
<input src="paypal/purchase.png" name="Submit" type="image" value="pruchase" alt="Purchase" />
</form>
```

Replacing the values to yours of-course.

Comment: I can't show the whole code as there is too much and it won't fit, but I have shown the `$Total` variable which should store the total along with the PayPal Button code.

Comment: Not quite, for some reason it is not picking up the values. See edit... This has now confused me a whole lot more

Comment: hi, can I also add the quantity to show on paypal screen as the current default quantity is 1 ?